# Using the Excel SMALL function with filtering criteria AND ignoring zeros

Tags: excel, formulas

I have a list of prices for products that are variations (different size, color) of multiple parent product.  Some products (for reasons not important to this question) have a price of zero.

I'm trying to write an excel formula that will return the lowest price for each parent product that is not zero

I've got this far:

=IF(SUMIFS(I:I,A:A,A3)=0,0,IF(AND(SUMIFS(I:I,A:A,A3)>0,MINIFS(I:I,A:A,A3)>0),MINIFS(I:I,A:A,A3),SMALL(IF(A:A=A3,I:I),2)))

Where I:I is the price column and A:A is the parent reference column

This works in all cases except where I have multiple variations of a parent product that have a zero value.

I need variables in a SMALL or MINIF function that will:
A. Only include the values for a single parent product in the calculation
B. Ignore any zeros in the calculation of the lowest value

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simply replace the 0s with a high number or simply remove the rows? would make your life much easier. `Minifs` is not a normal excel formula. Are you having some VBA function named that? If yes, we will need to look at its code

Comment: Why not use a **pivot table** to get the minimum from each group, instead of rewriting built-in functionality?

Comment: @ashleedawg 'Traditional' PivotTables would still show a min of zero, which the OP wants to ignore when calculating the minimum.

Comment: @RVPSRichard What version of Excel do you have. If you have Excel 2013 or later you could use a PivotTable based on something called the Data Model to do this, using something called DAX measures. (Earlier versions would require you to install the free PowerPivot add-in to do this using a PivotTable).

Comment: @jeffreyweir Absolutely not true. I just confirmed by taking a couple columns of values (with zero's and blanks) and in under 45 seconds had a pivot table showing minimums by group, excluding zero's .

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you filter out zeros? Might be worth posting as an answer.

Comment: sure, momentarily

Comment: @jeffreyweir An example is [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49973902/8112776).

Comment: Raunak, I'm understanding that minifs is a new formula starting in 2013 and I'm using Office 2016.  I like the pivot table idea, will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 'traditional' PivotTable to do this. See ashleedawg's great answer.

You can also use a 'OLAP' PivotTable that's based off something called the Data Model to do it, that has a small advantage over the 'traditional' PivotTable in that you don't need to clear the PageFilter after refreshing. (More on this at the bottom of my answer).

Any Excel version from Excel 2013 later has the DataModel built in by default, and you also get access to the DataModel in 2010 if you install Microsoft's free PowerPivot add-in. Using the DataModel, here's what you need to do:

Turn your data into an Excel Table using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut:

[image]

Make a PivotTable out of it, but be sure to check the *Add this data to the Data Model* option:

[image]

Add Group to the Rows pane of the PivotTable, then right-click on Table1 in the fields pane and select *Add Measure...*:

[image]

Give the new Measure a name (I've called it Min Without Zero) and type `=CALCULATE(MIN(Table1[Price]),Table1[Price]>0)` in the Formula box then push OK:

[image]

Put a tick in the Min Without Zero checkbox in the PivotTable fields list.

[image]

Bing! The PivotTable shows the min (excluding zero) of each group by price.

Edit: **I'd probably use ashleedawg's answer** if I was doing this myself. But there's one caveat: If you add additional data in future and refresh, then you need to clear the filter and reapply the zero exclusion to be absolutely sure that any new numbers in the data are included. By way of a demonstration, if I filter out zero from a PageField, then I get just the result I expect:

[image]

...and here's how the filter looks:

[image]

But if I add new data and refresh, note that nothing has changed in the PivotTable:

[image]

...and if I look at the filter I can see why:

[image]

That's because when you deselect something from a filter, you're not actually saying "Give me everything *except* this thing" but rather "Give me the *other* things *currently* visible in this list, but leave any new things unselected."

Easily enough fixed: Just clear the filter and deselect zero again (or write some VBA code to do it automatically on refresh).

Comment: Thank you Jeffery, I got this to work using the data model.  The straight filtering did not do it because I really needed to filter out the zeros before the minimum calculation took place.  Just filtering the results took all products where there was any zero and eliminated them.

Comment: I am refreshing this data nightly to update an online catalog.  Can I clarify that I only have to refresh the filter when I add new rows in the future, not just when I simply refresh existing rows?

Comment: This is working flawlessly, except for one issue.  I have a macro built to refresh other queries and won't run with the pivot table inserted.

Comment: Can you clarify further?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **Pivot Table** to easily create a **dynamic** list of minimums.  Blank cells are ignored by default, and zero's (or any other number you want) can be excluded a few ways; I think the easiest would be using the Pivot Table's Filter feature.

<sub>They say a picture is worth a thousand words so an animated GIF must be worth a million...  :)</sub>

[image: img]

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**Filter data in a PivotTable**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-data-in-a-pivottable-cc1ed287-3a97-4e95-b377-ddfafe79fa8f)
- Office.com : [**Display or hide zero values**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03)
- tips.net : [**Excluding Zero Values from a PivotTable**](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T009638_Excluding_Zero_Values_from_a_PivotTable.html)

Comment: Great answer. Timely reminder for me that you can have a field in the Filters area and in the Values area at the same time. (Technically they're different fields from Excel's perspective). Thanks for the timely reminder.

Comment: The only thing to watch out for with the above approach is that you may need to clear that filter and reapply it after you refresh the PivotTable, in the event that some additional data has been added to the PivotTable and the new data includes numbers that are less than what you had before. That's because when you deselect something from a filter, you're not actually saying "Give me everything except Zero" but rather "Give me the other numbers currently visible in this list". I'll add something to my answer that demonstrates this.

Comment: @jeffreyweir - no problem; my pleasure - this is exactly the kind of "gold" that keeps me interested in answering questions here.  I had forgotten about that functionality too, unless this question triggered my memory... and some of the best stuff comes out of the simplest questions.  Here we have multiple ways to accomplish the same task, all with correct results -- everybody wins!  That being said, I changed a value to `-1` and confirmed what you said: `-1` was now also ignored by default.

Comment: @jeffreyweir ...and perhaps you can return the favour my teaching me something related that's been bugging me forever:  **How the heck do you change the source data range on a Pivot Table?**  For example, if I want to add more columns or rows, I've always deleted and recreated the table for lack of a better way.  There's must be a "source data" option (just like a chart)??

Comment: @ashleedawg Damn, I should have thought of this. I don't know why but somehow I tend to write complicated formulas even though I know how to use a pivot table. And FYI that is quite simple, click a cell on the pivot table and then on top in the pivottable tools goto `analyze` > `Change Data Source`

Comment: The best option is to turn your source data into an Excel Table before you make the pivot, because then you never have to repoint PivotTables again. I did a guest post way back when on this at https://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/28/tables-pivottables-and-macros-music-to-your-ears/ Otherwise you've got to click the Change Data Source option from the PIvotTable Tools/Options tab.

Comment: or use a dynamic range as your table source

Comment: @RaunakThomas - damn, you'd think I would have noticed "the big button on the toolbar that says Change Data Source", at some point in the last 2 decades.  Pito would have pity.  ([Pito Salas](https://www.linkedin.com/in/pitosalas/) "accidentally fathered" the Pivot Table in 1986, when he was just trying to make a cool report for his boss at Lotus.)

Comment: @QHarr - as in a Named Range?  ...very cool, I never thought of that either... And I'm always the one telling *other people* to use pivot tables instead of whatever method they're planning on using for "whatever"... lol.

Comment: you can use dynamic named range or entire columns (less preferable - if no unrelated data in same columns)

Comment: Thanks for all the help, guys.

Answer (score 1):

If the input data is sorted based on the parent reference level you can simply

- use offset to find the required parent reference cells containing the price
- Find the k-th smallest value using the `SMALL` formula (i.e. the smallest value)
- Put a if condition to give you the 2nd smallest value if the smallest is 0

Place this in the 1st row

```
=IF(SMALL(OFFSET($I$1,MATCH(C1,$C:$C,0)-1,0,COUNTIF($C:$C,C1)),1)=0,SMALL(OFFSET($I$1,MATCH(C1,$C:$C,0)-1,0,COUNTIF($C:$C,C1)),2),SMALL(OFFSET($I$1,MATCH(C1,$C:$C,0)-1,0,COUNTIF($C:$C,C1)),1))
```

Comment: Nice one.  This would have been my second choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a formula approach, you can use an IF statement to return a value if that value is over zero, and otherwise return FALSE, as functions like MIN conveniently ignore FALSE.

As per my other answer I recommend you turn the data into an Excel Table first with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut, as shown below. Then in a summary table you can use the following array-entered formula in E2:

`=MIN(IF(Table1[Price]>0,IF(Table1[Group]=D2,Table1[Price])))`

(Array-entered means you push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of pushing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> like you usually do)

And here's the result:

[image]